# Reload wicket components after a button click event using AJAX

Tags: java, html, ajax, wicket, reload

I am using wicket components here. My view is as below.

[image]

I need to regenerate the report and reload the report frame with the button click (GO). But this div is not reloading even I replaced old element with a new report element. Can anyone help me with this?

```
form.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("goLink") {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println(reportType+"go button clicked");
            final IResourceStream stream = renderItems();
            //generate report and create a new component using that.
            Component component = new AIAIframe("reportFrame", stream);
            component.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            this.addOrReplace(component);
            System.out.println("new framwe added reportframe");
        }
    });
    add(form);
```

Please find the markup.html below

```
<wicket:extend>
<div style="margin-left:3%;">
    <form wicket:id="form">
        <span>
            <h4>Report Erscheinung Auswahl</h4>

            <select wicket:id="chooseType" style="margin-left:5%;">
            <option>Kostenvoranschlag</option>
            <option>Aufträge</option>
            <option>Rechnungen</option>
        </select>
        </span>
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="downloadLink" wicket:id="goLink">GO</a>
        </span>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
<style>
    a.downloadLink {
      width: 115px;
      height: 25px;
      background: #4E9CAF;
      padding: 6px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .aia-center {
       margin:0 auto;
       padding: 6px;
    }
</style>
<div class="aia-center">
    <span>Download as: </span>
    <select wicket:id="formatSelect">
    </select>
    <a href="#" class="downloadLink" wicket:id="downloadLink">Download</a>
</div>
<span style="height: 100%; width: 100%" wicket:id="reportFrame"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `target.add(component)` if you want this `component` to be re-rendered with the Ajax response.

Since you re-create the component with wicket:id="reportFrame" you need to make sure that the initially rendered one (before the Ajax request) also had `.setOutputMarkupId(true)` so that the Ajax logic can find it in the browser DOM and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get this error when I tried that.                              
ERROR - PnWebExceptionHandler      - org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup not found for Component: [AIAIframe [Component id = reportFrame]]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2019/03/26 09:03:00 | org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Markup not found for Component: [AIAIframe [Component id = reportFrame]]

Comment: I have updated with the wicket markup.html in the question. Could you please have a look.

Comment: I have added your what you said by removing this.addOrReplace(component). Then I got this warning message Component '[AIAIframe [Component id = reportFrame]]' with markupid: 'id407' not rendered because it was already removed from page

Comment: You have to have both the `addOrReplace(component)` (adds the component to the component tree) and `target.add(component)` (tells Wicket to render it in the AjaxRequest) in there.
The problem is, that you are calling `addOrReplace(component)` on `this`, which referes to the AjaxLink in that context. You probably want to call it on your page though, since your graph is **not** a child of the GO-Link but rather a direct child of the page, according to your html snippet. So `getPage().addOrReplace(component)` should work in your specific case.